# I get an undefined error with reactjs mozilla

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, mozilla

I am developing an application using reactjs. It works fine on chrome with the following codes.
But I get the following error on browser like mozilla, opera.

[image]

What is the solution to this?

```
class DefaultHeader extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: this.props.account_profile.profile.first_name,
      lastname: this.props.account_profile.profile.last_name
    }
}
```

render

```
<label>{ this.props.account_profile.profile.username + " " + this.props.account_profile.profile.lastname} </label>
```

I can get this.props information with chrome. but I cannot get the same information with browsers such as mozilla and opera and it gives an error.

Comment: I can get this.props information with chrome.
but I cannot get the same information with browsers such as mozilla and opera and it gives an error.

Comment: Thats some mystery. Try to make a demo sample